# Gas stove discolored after painted when cooked in extra large pot

Tags: appliances, repainting

Large pot causes discoloration

On stove top since it was repainted even though I used high heat appliance paint!  Is there a paint made especially for gas stove tops that I should have used?

Comment: What paint did you use? Pictures?

Comment: No paint is as heat-tolerant as the original porcelain. That's a thin layer of glass melted on the steel in a kiln/oven, not paint, even though it's commonly referred to as "enamel" - pretty sure the paint being called enamel is one of those marketing fibs to make the buyer think it's better than it is, for that matter...

Comment: You might try a dark-brown or black paint that will show heat-damage less, or a high-temperature automotive paint. However, the best , and perhaps mos economical, choice would be to find a used stove top of the correct color; they're easily replaced. Check used appliance dealers near you, rather than mail order, so you can look for a unit in good shape.